# How to generate repeated sequence in expression transformation

Tags: informatica

Hey guys i want to generate repeating sequence in expression transformation in INFORMATICA .
Sequence should like this
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1

Comment: Is this a real problem or some sort of interview quiestion? What have you tried so far and what issues have you been facing? Can you show your solution as-is?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a Sequence Generator Transformation?